# Is it possible to write an Unambiguous Grammar for Two Hard Language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I came across a very hard interview exam. It was asked wrote an unambiguous grammar for two following language, Who can hint it to solve it?

> 1) $L = \{a^n b^{2n} c: n\geq 0\} \cup \{a^{2n} b^n d: n\geq 0\}$
>
> 2) $L = \{a^n b a^{2n}: n \geq 0\} \cup \{a^{2n} b a^n: n\geq 0\}$

I know If $L_1,L_2$ are two disjoint context-free languages which are not inherently ambiguous, then $L_1 \cup L_2$ is also a context-free language which is not inherently ambiguous. but I couldent write grammar for these.

Comment: First write an unambiguous grammar for $\{a^n b^{2n}\}$; then adapt that. While you're at it, show some work or some of your own ideas; that will help people to help you (and otherwise your question without context will likely be rapidly closed).

Comment: @Magdiragdag I do it, but failed. this is very hard for contest I think !!

Comment: I am curious, was this for a specific job or just a generic test of some sort?

Comment: So, some ideas to show at least an attempt: what is, according to you, an unambigious grammar?

Comment: @Magdiragdag if one parse tree be at there.

Comment: @copper.hat i couldent understand your comment !?

Comment: I am curious to know for what sort of job it is useful to be able to create unambiguous grammars for a cooked up language?

Comment: I think for proving that this is unambiguity  :)  @copper.hat

Comment: Anyway, I repeat my first comment: first write an unambiguous grammar for $\{a^n b^{2n}, n \geq 0\}$; the remainder is just variations on a theme.

Comment: And you are required to prove that the grammar is unambiguous?

Comment: it's very useful thanks @Magdiragdag

Comment: yes @copper.hat exactly ! it's fun for me. because my contest is over two days ago and i didnt solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

Spoiler alert.

My solutions.

1)

$$
L ::= Bc \mid Cd \\
B ::= aBbb \mid \epsilon \\
C ::= aaCb \mid \epsilon
$$

2)

$$ 
L ::= A \mid B \\
A ::= b \mid aAaa \\
B ::= aaba \mid aaBa
$$

Notice that the base case of the B recursion is $aaba$, not $\epsilon$. This removes ambiguity.

Comment: I try to find a counterexample? how you prove it :)

Comment: Not sure. To me it's just intuitive. If you've seen enough of these, you can do them.

Comment: This might not be a helpful answer then.

Comment: @Nima Nakisa: you prove by induction over the size of a parse tree that a string of symbols belongs to the language specified by the grammar iff it satisfies the specification given in the problem.

Comment: @user3491648: I think it is a very helpful answer - the OP is looking a gift horse in the mouth.